# UPDATE prepared statement PHP Error

Tags: php, prepared-statement, hitcounter

I am creating a dynamic page which changes depending on which ever post the user clicks onto.  I am also wanting the views (hit-counter) the page gets to go up by one each time the page is loaded.  I am currently getting the following error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\Users\PC\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\post.php on line 13

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'php/config.php';
$post = $_GET['post'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum WHERE ForumId = '$post'");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($ForumId,$ForumTitle,$ForumPostText,$PostDate,$Views);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

$Views = 1;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE 'forum' SET 'Views' = 'Views'+ 1 WHERE 'ForumId' = '?' ");
$stmt->bind_param('i',$post);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();


?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
// The rest of the webpage yada yada yada
```

Comment: check var_dump($stmt) to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a problem in the query.

Take note, that PDO statement dont need single quotes

Try with this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE forum SET Views = Views+ 1 WHERE ForumId = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $post);
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove (`'`) single quotes in update query and use backtick (`) instead

So

```
"UPDATE `forum` SET `Views` = Views+ 1 WHERE `ForumId` = ?"
```

Comment: could the ? also be inside ` or it should be without anything?

Answer (score 1):

Although Krish R's response is the solution, one of the things you will want to do in cases like this, is look at `$mysqli->error` to actually get an error message. This will tell you that you have a syntax error near `'forum' SET 'Vi...`. That in itself should indicate that that specific character (the first ' in the string) is the most likely cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'php/config.php';
$post = $_GET['post'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM forum WHERE ForumId = $post");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($ForumId,$ForumTitle,$ForumPostText,$PostDate,$Views);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

$Views = 1;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE forum SET Views = Views + 1 WHERE ForumId = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $post);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();


?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
```